# JqueryMobile Nativedroid2 tabs nested inside other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, tabs, nativedroid

I have nested two tabs inside standard nativedroid2 demo "colors" tab. Thought that will work as regular jQuery mobile tabs but it appears that it is not working as intended.

When I navigate to colors tab and click on a sub tab the sub tab content swipes from the left/right, displays on the monitor, and swipes further left/right showing blank page. Any ideas how to fix it ?

This is how tabs are set:

```
<ul data-role="nd2tabs">
        <li data-tab="friends">Friends</li>
        <li data-tab="work" data-tab-active="true">Work</li>
        <li data-tab="holiday">Holiday</li>
        <li data-tab="colors">Colors</li>
</ul>
```

This is the content of Colors tab:

```
<div data-role="nd2tab" data-tab="colors">
    <ul data-role="nd2tabs" data-swipe="true">
        <li class="ui-btn ui-mini nd2-btn-icon-block nd2Tabs-nav-item" data-tab="new" data-tab-active="true"><a style="font-size:10px; color:black">newly created tab</a></li>
        <li class="ui-btn ui-mini nd2-btn-icon-block nd2Tabs-nav-item" data-tab="old"> <a style="font-size:10px; color:black">very old tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div data-role="nd2tab" data-tab="new">
        <p>some new content</p>
    </div>                  
    <div data-role="nd2tab" data-tab="old">
        <p>very very old content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/peterPP1/7761152a/1/